# Open all PDF files in a viewer

Tags: php, .htaccess, pdf, mod-rewrite

I have many PDF files in directories and sub-directories.
I wanted a way when user open the link of the pdf file eg: http://website.me/sample.pdf or http://website.me/du/sample.pdf 
will open in it a viewer !

All I need is to pass the file path to the viewer.php so it will display the pdf file.

I tried this in .htaccess file,

```
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteRule \.(pdf)$ viewer.php?id=$1
```

for a test I echo what is passed to the php file, I found it is only "pdf" no file name nor file path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed the rewrite code to

```
RewriteRule ^([^.]+\.pdf) viewer.php?id=$1
```

it worked as expected and each path is showed correctly!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-.]+)/?$ viewer.php?id=$1   [NC,L]
```

viewer.php

```
<?php
      echo $_GET['id'];
?>
```

Print id it will show you the passed value. assign it to variable and use. It works fine from my end

Comment: it doesn't work !, it showed the pdf as default. remember I just need pdf to be passed to the viewer

Comment: Is your rewrite mode enabled?

Comment: yup as the code I have posted worked but not as expected